# A lot of php processes popping at once and eats all memory

Tags: php, memory, webserver, server, administration

I have a cloud server in Rackspace with cPanel installed. I have some 16 sites running on it. Out of them 14 sites run under a single account (this is a Drupal multisite installation). Everything has been running fine for last 5 months. Recently my server became unresponsive and had to be rebooted. Later it was found out that the server ran out of memory.

The issue now continue to occur intermittently.  At that time I can  find a lot of php processes popping out at once, memory usage increases at that time and the comes to nearly 200 MB out of the total 8GB.

/usr/bin/php /home/username/public_html/index.php

All sites become inaccessible. The load average also spikes. After 5-8 minutes the huge number of php processes disappears and then memory usage also comes to normal. This lasts not more than 5-6 minutes

The issue now continue to occur intermittently. And I checked all server logs and could not find any trace of the issue.  I checked the server using maldet, rkhunter and could not find any traces of malicious codes or back-doors

The strange issue is that the issue does not occur during the most peak hours. It occurs during off-peak hours as well. There is no pattern in which this issue occurs.

I can find that there were 150 php instances running at once yesterday.

Can someone guide me in the correct direction? Is this a server side issue or has something to do with the internal site functions?

Comment: Whats in your access log and syslog? `top` shows abnormal memory usage?

Comment: not the right forum for this kind of question. Look at Super User (superuser.com) or Server Fault (serverfault.com) forums.

Comment: Have you checked what your traffic looks like? It could just be a case of one or many spiders getting caught on your sites and hammering away at the URLs.